# How to call Python using PHP and pass some variables from PHP to python?

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

I want to call python in PHP like we all PHP using ajax in java script the along with calling python script I also need to pass some values to python and it should return result to PHP page

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but you'll likely want the exec() function which can execute external programs. Here's the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can setup a http server on Python and let it running, then you send get or post request from your PHP code. 
I recommend you search about flask.